# Excel Outlook VBA Save Unread Emails to a Network Folder

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, vba

I was able to build an Outlook VBA script in Excel that would save down the just the attachments of "Unread" messages in a specific Outlook subfolder to a folder on my network and then mark the message as "Read".

I'm trying to save the emails as well. I've been having issues trying to save the outlook message to my network. The closest I've been able to come was by adding the code in bold below. Although I'm not getting the desired output.

As in, the attachments are being saved to the folder, H:\Testing\XY\, and I'd like to save the Outlook messages to the H:\Testing\XY\Emails" folder. Meanwhile, I just want the emails to be saved with the subject name and the date the email was received. When I run the VBA code though, the emails are being saved to the folder, H:\Testing\XY\, and the the file names are Emails.msg.

The attachments are saving as I'd like them to though. Any help to complete this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub SaveEmailAndAttach()

Dim myOlapp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim avDate() As String
Dim vDate As String
Dim i As Long
Dim myEmailPath As String

ReDim Preserve avDate(3)

Set myOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNamespace = myOlapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Const myAttachPath As String = "H:\Testing\XY\"
**myEmailPath = enviro & "H:\Testing\XY\Emails"**

Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Auto").Folders("Manual")
For Each myItem In myFolder.Items
    If myItem.UnRead = True Then
        avDate = Split(CStr(myItem.ReceivedTime), "/")
        vDate = avDate(0) & "-" & avDate(1) & "-" & Mid(avDate(2), 1, 4)

        If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments

            If UCase(Right(myAttachment.Filename, 4)) = "XLSX" Then
                i = i + 1
                myAttachment.SaveAsFile (myAttachPath & vDate & " " & myAttachment.Filename)

                End If
                Next
                **myItem.SaveAs myEmailPath & " " & vDate & ".msg"**
                myItem.UnRead = False
        End If
    End If
Next
Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close (-ish). The main problem is the missing trailing `\` from `myEmailPath`. Adding that (and removing the extraneous `enviro &`) leads to this declaration:

```
Const myEmailPath = "H:\Testing\XY\Emails\"
```

Your code to save the email should now work, as is. However, I've taken the liberty to extend it to also include the subject as per your requirement:

```
myItem.SaveAs myEmailPath & vDate & " " & myItem.Subject & ".msg"
```

However, since the subject can contain characters that are forbidden in a filename, it would be better to strip out those characters. The following code will do just that (for Windows):

```
'v0.1.1
Dim strSubject As String: strSubject = myItem.Subject
Dim varForbiddenChar
For Each varForbiddenChar In Split("\ / : * ? "" < > |")
  strSubject = Replace(strSubject, varForbiddenChar, "-")
Next varForbiddenChar
```

Of course, the character stripping code needs to be inserted just before the code to save the email, and *that* code needs to be modified as follows:

```
myItem.SaveAs myEmailPath & vDate & " " & strSubject & ".msg"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info! 

The adjustments for the myEmailPath worked perfectly.  

I could't get the subject line working though 'myItem.SaveAs myEmailPath & vDate & " " & myItem.Subject & ".msg"'  I kept getting the the following  "Run-time error '-2147287037 (80030003)': The operation failed".

Comment: @DrewDaddio That could be because the subject is not acceptable as part of a filename.  Try `Debug.Print myEmailPath & vDate & " " & myItem.Subject & ".msg"` to see if that part works. Also try just outputting the value of `myItem.Subject`. I didn't test the code as I don't use Outlook, but that should have worked.

Comment: that is exactly it. The subject has a "/" in it.

Comment: @DrewDaddio I've updated my answer to include code to strip forbidden characters.

Comment: It took me a little bit of time to complete due to vacations & moving but I just wanted to update and say that the character stripping code is working great! I had a little bit of a learning curve but was able to get it working by putting the 'varForbiddenChar' immediately before `myEmailPath & vDate & " " & myItem.Subject & ".msg"`. Thank you again!

Comment: @DrewDaddio It's great that you managed to combine my two code snippets. I've updated my answer in case another reader has problems doing so. I've also slightly improved the character stripping code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to help others with VBA for Excel using Outlook, let me resume the above discussion with few input of mine to complete the answer.

This questions is about :

1- save a "Unread" messages in a personal Outlook subfolder to a folder on a shared network directory

2- mark the message as "Read".

3- mark the email as a blue category (optional)

Please note that saving the email in .msg format include attachment in the email.

Hope this help you as much as it does for me ;-)

```
 `Sub SavePersonnalInboxEmail()
 'requires reference to Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library
 'requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
 Dim myOlapp As Outlook.Application
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim avDate() As String
 Dim i As Long
 Dim myEmailPath As String
 Dim varForbiddenChar
 ReDim Preserve avDate(3)
 Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim xObjItem As Object
 Dim vDate, xPath As String
 Dim strSubject, xFileName, xName As String
 Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
 Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
 Dim VPN As String
 Dim olExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
 Dim selectedItem As Object

 Set myOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set myNamespace = myOlapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

 '**********Check that you can reach the shared network directory *********************
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
VPN = fso.FolderExists("H:\Testing\XY\Emails\")
If VPN = False Then
    MsgBox "The shared network is unavailable", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
End If

    Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Auto").Folders("Manual")
    Set olItems = myFolder.Items

myEmailPath = "H:\Testing\XY\Emails\"

' ********* Loop to select the chosen email *****************
For Each myItem In myFolder.Items

If myItem.SenderName = "DrewDaddio" Then
    
    If myItem.UnRead = True Then
        If InStr(1, myItem.Subject, "Test") Then
        

' ********* Select the email with the cursor ****************
            Set olExplorer = myOlapp.ActiveExplorer
            olExplorer.Activate
            olExplorer.ClearSelection
            Set selectedItem = myItem
            olExplorer.AddToSelection selectedItem

 '************* Save the email in the shared network drive including attachment *************
            For Each xObjItem In Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection
                avDate = Split(CStr(myItem.ReceivedTime), "/")
                vDate = avDate(0) & "-" & avDate(1) & "-" & Mid(avDate(2), 1, 2)

                For Each varForbiddenChar In Split("\ / : * ? "" < > |")
                         strSubject = Replace(myItem.Subject, varForbiddenChar, "-")
                Next varForbiddenChar

                If xObjItem.Class = olMail Then
                    Set myItem = xObjItem
                    xName = vDate & "_" & strSubject & ".msg"
                    xFileName = myEmailPath
                    xPath = xFileName + xName
                    xObjItem.SaveAs xPath, olMSG
                End If

                myItem.UnRead = False
                myItem.Categories = "Blue category"   'optional
                myItem.Save
                strAddress = ""
                strSubject = ""
                vDate = ""
                Exit Sub
            Next
        End If
    End If
End If
Next
End sub`
```